# How do I modify a private variable in a base class with a derived member function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

My full question because I couldn't fit it all on the title is:how 2 modify a private variable in the base class with a derived class B member function that will call a member function thats been overrided in the base class A which will also modify a different private member variable in the derived class B. I'm having a really tough time trying to figure this out because I can't figure out how to modify two private member variables that are in different classes in two member functions that come from different classes. This is what I have for my code so far. I'll make comments in the code on the issue i'm trying to solve

In my .h file I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A();
    A(string name_holder, double balance_holder);
    int take(float amount);
    string getName();
    double getBalance();
    void output();
private:
    string name;
    double balance;
};

class B:public A{
public:
    B();
    B(int number_of_withdrawal_holder);
    int take(float amount);//overriding
    void output();
private:
    static int count;
};
```

In my .cpp file I have

```
#include "Header.h"


A::A()
{
    name=" ";
    balance=0;
}

A::A(string name_holder,double balance_holder)
{
    name=name_holder;
    balance=balance_holder;
}
int A::take(float amount)
{
    if (balance >= amount && amount>=0)//if the amount is less than or equal to the balance and is nonnegative
    {
        balance-=amount;
        cout<<"ok"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout <<"Insufficient funds for the withdrawal to take place"<<endl;
    return 1;

}

string A::getName()
{
    return name;
}
double A::getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

void A::output()
{
    cout<<"Name: "<<getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"Balance: "<<getBalance()<<endl;
}

int B::count=0;

B::B()
{
    count=0;
}
B::B(int number_of_withdrawal_holder)
{
    count=number_of_withdrawal_holder;
}
int B::take(float amount)
{
    if(count==0)//if this is the first withdrawal
    {
        ++count;
        return BankAccount::take(amount);
    }

    //the bottom part of the code gets excuted if you already withdrew atleast once-you pay a fee of 1.50(in other words i want to do a function call to the first withdraw function and subtract 1.50 from the member variable balance but I also want to modify count in the base class function take

    ++number_of_withdrawals;

    return BankAccount::withdraw(amount);
}
```

If anyone can help me out that would be great!

Comment: What functions, members and so on are we talking here about exactly? I think it's quite difficult to see...

Comment: `int take(float amount);//overriding` Since `A::take` is not virtual, `B::take` doesn't in fact override it, but hides it.

Comment: and - what is `BankAccount`? (eg. you have a definition of BankAccount::setName, but not declaration).

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempt by members of `B` to access or modify private members of `A`. What specifically seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please rephrase the initial paragraph or break it in shorter sentences. As it is, it's quite hard to understand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't know how to. I showed the function call with take but i don't know how to modify balance from there and then increase count because those two are in different classes

Comment: In what way does `++count; return BankAccount::take(amount);` not achieve the desired outcome? It modifies `balance` and also increments `count`. (I assume by `BankAccount` you mean `A`; if not, then explain what `BankAccount` is and how it fits into the picture). I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: I think you doing it wrong.. your base class is an _account_ which provides you sort of interface to transactions for a specified account, so you shouldn't to modify any internals of the base class rather then what's provided by a public interface, so your 'fee' is also a withdraw operation

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I only want return A::take(amount); and yah i do mean A instead of bankaccount but basically i want it to only modify balance if count is 1 but count is a derived memeber variable so i cant include count in my base member function as a guideline to check wether or not i should modify balance

Comment: "i want it to only modify balance" What does "it" refer to in this sentence - `A`, `B`, something else? If the behavior of `A` should depend on `count`, then `count` should be a member of `A`. What was the purpose of splitting the code into two classes in the first place? It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve with your design (and generic names like `A` and `B` don't help).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i def agree with you but it was in the directions to split it up

Comment: Well, the "directions" probably explained the reason for the requirement - a reason that you neglected to mention. It's kind of difficult to help you with a design problem when you never explained the goal said design is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know I didn't leave any details out but I'm just gonna make my private variables in my base class protected so i can modify them in my derived class function

Answer (score 2):

A `private` member is private even to derived subclasses. If you want to allow a derived subclass to access a member, make it `protected` instead of `private`. Such members are still not public, but can be accessed by subclasses.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if this is actually your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Moved to an answer:

I think you doing it wrong.. your base class is an account which provides you sort of interface to transactions for a specified account, so you shouldn't to modify any internals of the base class rather then what's provided by a public interface, so your 'fee' is also a withdraw operation..

As also truly mentioned in comments, A::take() should be declared virtual

```
class A {
  ...
    virtual int take(float amount);
  ...
}
class B: public A {

    B() {
        m_nNumberOfWithdraw = 0;
    }

    B::B(int number_of_withdrawal_holder) {
        m_nNumberOfWithdraw =number_of_withdrawal_holder;
    }

    int B::take(float amount) {

          int nResult = A::take(m_nNumberOfWithdraw > 0 ? amount + 1.50 :amount);

          if (nResult == 0)
               m_nNumberOfWithdraw++;

          return nResult;
    }


    protected:

        int      m_nNumberOfWithdraw;
};
```